# SQL syntax about joining several tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like these:

Table name: students

```
id * | name
-----+------
 1   | Alice
```

Table name: teachers

```
id * | name
-----+------
 2   | Bob
```

Table name: messages

```
msg_id * | from | message
---------+------+----------------------------
   100   |    1 | Hi, my name is Alice. I'm student.
   101   |    2 | Hi, my name is Bob. I'm teacher.
   102   }    1 | Another message from Alice.
```

- = Primary key.

Can you help me to make **a SQL query** with the results as below:

```
msg_id | name  | message
-------+-------+-----------------------------------
   100 | Alice | Hi, my name is Alice. I'm student.
   101 | Bob   | Hi, my name is Bob. I'm teacher.
   102 | Alice | Another message from Alice.
```

Comment: If you got a single table for storing the message by 2 different entities i.e. teachers and students(here), then you must have another flag that is going to help you determine the "from" field in the message table belongs to which table i.e. the teachers or the students table.

Comment: As noted above, this is an awful data format. You really need to combine the `students` and `teachers` tables and add a column for the `role` (student or teacher or possibly parent, etc.). Then your job will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your table structures, and there are many alternatives such as having a person table with a flag that identifies the type of person they are.  But getting back to your original and unmodified structures.  The "from" APPEARS that YOU are controlling the next "ID" in the Student or Teachers table respectively.  As student is 1, teacher is 2 (hence the IMPRESSION you are controlling the ID).  Would there EVER be an instance where you have a student ID = 1 AND a teacher ID = 1?

If NOT, then you could do with double left-join to each table and pull whichever is NOT NULL

```
select
      m.id,
      coalesce( s.name, t.name ) as Person,
      case when s.id is null then 'teacher' else 'student' end WhoAmI,
      m.message
   from
      Messages m
         left join Students s
            on m.from = s.id
         left join Teachers t
            on m.from = t.id
```

You can obviously grab whatever order / fields, but you can see how I differentiate the pieces above.

Answer (score 0):

Th entity field is going to help you to determine the person who sent you the message as there exists two entities i.e. the student and the teacher.

```
msg_id | from | entity | message
-------+------+--------+-------------------
   100 |    1 | 1      | Hi, my name is Alice. I'm student.
   101 |    2 | 2      | Hi, my name is Bob. I'm teacher.
```

Considering entity to be 1 for students and 2 for teachers.

Based on that:

```
SELECT msg_id, IF(students.name is null, teachers.name, students.name) as name, message FROM messages
LEFT JOIN students ON students.id = messages.id AND entity = 1
LEFT JOIN teachers ON teachers.id = messages.id AND entity = 2
```

Please try this, if this doesn't resolves your query do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

just to make sure that your message contains the student name, i added `t2.message like concat('%', t2.name,'%')`

```
select t1.msg_id, t2.name, t1.message  
from messages t1
inner join students t2 on t2.message like concat('%', t2.name,'%') and t1.from = t2.id
```